# array codeigniter with mongoDB

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb

Please help me, i have a case that must be solve immediately due to strict deadline.. :(
I have an idea using preg_match or preg_split to solve this, and had tried so many way to use it but still not understand how to use it. 
Maybe someone could guide me, about this case so i could get more understanding about how to use preg_match or preg_split.

//from this string

```
$temp = "{foo:bar,bar:foo},{_id:1,nama:1,nim:1}";
```

//how to assign it to array so the result will be like this

```
Array
(
[0]=>foo:bar,bar:foo
[1]=>_id:1,nama:1,nim:1
)
```

//also the second string

```
$temp2 = "_id:1,nama:1,nim:1";
```

//how to assign it to array so the result will be like this

```
Array
(
[0] => _id
[1] => nama
[2] => nim
)
```

Thank you for your guidance and the help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Notice the keys and the strings are quoted and the `[` `]` around $temp to make it an array, for the second part I convert `array[1]` into a json string then back into an array then use array_keys to create an array of the keys.

```
$temp = '{"foo":"bar","bar":"foo"},{"_id":1,"nama":1,"nim":1}';
$temp = "[$temp]";
$array = json_decode($temp);

$keys = array_keys(json_decode(json_encode($array[1]), true));
```

[`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
<?php

$str1 = "{foo:bar,bar:foo},{_id:1,nama:1,nim:1}";
preg_match_all('/\{(.+?)\},?/', $str1, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);

$str2 = "_id:1,nama:2,nim:3";
preg_match_all('/(\w+)\:\w+,?/', $str2, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);

?>
```

Result:

```
array
  0 => string 'foo:bar,bar:foo' (length=15)
  1 => string '_id:1,nama:1,nim:1' (length=18)
array
  0 => string '_id' (length=3)
  1 => string 'nama' (length=4)
  2 => string 'nim' (length=3)
```

Reference:

- [preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)
- [preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)
- [preg_match_all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Explaination:

1. First of all, we should decide which function to use. As the manual said:

   > `preg_match()` returns the number of times pattern matches. That will be
   >   either `0` times (no match) or `1` time because `preg_match()` will stop
   >   searching after the first match. `preg_match_all()` on the contrary will
   >   continue until it reaches the end of subject. `preg_match()` returns
   >   `FALSE` if an error occurred.

   and

   > `preg_split()` returns an array containing substrings of subject split
   >   along boundaries matched by pattern.

   As your goal is to capture the content between the curly brace, I choose 
   `preg_match_all` to easily handle the task. Of course, you can do it with
   `preg_split` the hard way :)
2. Come to the patterns: it's all about [Regular Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

   1. `\{(.+?)\},?`: We capture the content inside a pair of curly braces. `+` stand to skip empty braces like `{}`. Try put some empty pair `{}` into `$str1` and change `+` to `*` and see what happens. Also the `?` mark to specify non-greedy. `+?` mean that we don't need something like `foo}{bar` from `{foo}{bar}`, but `foo` and `bar` alone. `,?` mean there can be a comma or not.
   2. `(\w+)\:\w+,?`: We capture the `key` in a pair `key:value`

Hope this help :)